# Run specific commands without op on a minecrft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm using world guard on my server and I protected the hub area but there are some buttons for missions winch runs commands, but when a player (without op) uses that button I get an error message "You do not have permission to perform this command...". In world guard I set that command with `/region flag (/rg flag -w "world" -h 4 hub_protect allowed-cmds /setblock 165 73 185 redstone_block)` and it's still not working. Any solutions?

It is Minecraft 1.14.4.

Answer (score 1):

To grant permissions for other plugins on a server, you'll need to use a permissions manager such as [LuckPerms](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/luckperms-an-advanced-permissions-plugin.28140/). With this, you can grant players the ability to use the specific WorldGuard command you want.

You can find [how to use it here.](https://github.com/lucko/LuckPerms/wiki)

Comment: No. No. No. The player (without op) only runs the /setblock command. I tried to set this with "/region flag (/rg flag -w "world" -h 4 hub_protect allowed-cmds /setblock 165 73 185 redstone_block" command and its still not working.

Comment: You should still be able to do it with a permissions manager @ÁdámKara